# Using app_offline.htm to take an app offline while updating dll's fails while updating dll's

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, app-offline.htm

So I sometimes use app_offline.htm to take an app offline while I upload a new version.

However, while I am in the process of uploading larger dll's, I get the yellow error-screen saying the dll could not be loaded.

This seems to be out of sync with my expectations of what app_offline.htm does (stops the app entirely), and also provides the users with errors in stead of the nice app_offline.htm I put up.

Am I doing something wrong or is this behavior by design?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really clear on the error message you're getting.  Are you saying that it's telling you that the .dll's are still in use?

Comment: Update with the actual error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The app_offline.htm is shut-down the application, but not fully stop the compiler.**

So, on the first dll that you have upload, the compiler see the different and start the compilation again... so then when you try for the next dll probably is used by the compilation and can not be delete/replaced.

There is also the possibility that even if you ask for shut-down the application still make process and use this dll.

What I do, I upload all files on the server in one other directory, I open the app_offline.htm, then I wait for all my pool to close (I have place message on the application end) and then I copy from the server all the update files fast. The different is that with the ftp the time to upload is bigger than the time the compiler trigger for recompile the global functions from dll.

To see that even with the app_offline.htm , the system is still make compiles, just use Process Explorer and see the compilations.

What is compile ? I think that compile the dlls except the pages.

**The message is from compiler that try to compile the program, from the first dll that you have upload the compiler is triggered and start the new compilation, now you uploading the next one, and while is trying to make the compile, the dll is locked by ftp.**