# Ftp Dll: could not put file 550 can't access file I/O Error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, ftp

When trying to ftp a build of a ASP.NET site, I sometimes get this error. Is there way to prevent this, a configuration in web.config of IIS that prevents dlls being locked?

Comment: Do you open the app_offline.htm ? Here is a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737164/using-app-offline-htm-to-take-an-app-offline-while-updating-dlls-fails-while-upd/3737511#3737511